# Bash script to parse log file

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, catalina

I am trying to parse a log file to extract userIds. Below is how each log is setup in catalina.out. I want to extract just the userId. How would I do that. I tried awk and grep but it returns the entire block instead of just userId. Also, I want to get every unique userId once, because the same user could log in multiple times obviously so I just want the file I write it to to just have it once. Could you guys please help me get an idea where to start? Thanks!

**Here are the commands I've tried:**

```
awk '/userId/' catalina.out

grep "userId" catalina.out
```

When I do this instead of returning back the userId, it returns back the entire block (as seen below)

**Log format:**

```
03:44:04.373 [127.0.0.1-8009-exec-178] 
INFO  c.c.c.x.x.w.f.AuthenticationFilter - cachObj
{"guid":"guid","userId":"userId","isPrimary":false,"accessToken":"accessToken"}
```

Comment: Looks like JSON output, use a proper parser for it

Comment: Is your log sample 1 line or multiple?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your userids will be found like "userId":"test_chumma" etc etc, if this is the case then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F'[":,]' '/userId/{print $11}'  Input_file
```

Off course if you have more requirements then kindly show us more sample output with full conditions.

Comment: I tried using your command with my input file name and I don't get back any results.

Comment: @redsox2002: Kindly post more sample Input_file into post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Another example with awk:

```
awk -F"[:,]" '$1 ~ /^{/ {gsub("\"","",$4); print $4}' inFile.log
```

Here we split the records by a colon `:` or a comma `,` using the awk command's `F` flag `-F[:,]`, Then if the first field in the record `$1` starts with a bracket `/^{/` (where we use the regex operator `~` for the condition) then we swap out the 4th field's double quotes with nothing `gsub("\"","",$4)` and print the result `print $4`

```
$ cat test
03:44:04.373 [127.0.0.1-8009-exec-178]
INFO  c.c.c.x.x.w.f.AuthenticationFilter - cachObj
{"guid":"guid","userId":"aUserId","isPrimary":false,"accessToken":"accessToken"}
$ awk -F"[:,]" '$1 ~ /^{/ {gsub("\"","",$4); print $4}' test
aUserId
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't get back any results using this command

Comment: I used your three line example log file from above. I will post the exact results of running this on my box. Perhaps your log file is formatted differently then your example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution combining awk and cut from unix:

```
awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}' catalina.out | cut -f2 -d","
"userId"
```

But this will also work only for the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}' file 

userId
```